# variable array does not return a value when selected

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a bit of a struggle to dynamically create variables like you do in a for-next loop like

```
for I is 1 to 10
 wg($i)
next
```

I've tried the following approach:

```
<xsl:variable name="workgroups">
  <xsl:for-each select="//page/workgroups/workgroup">
    <child elem="{@elem}">
      <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </child>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then later using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($workgroups)/child[@elem='0']"/>
```

Although I can see in the variable $workgroups the 7 names that have been selected and added in the for-each loop, the value-of select does not return anything

I would expect to have an array like:
    workgroups[0] - value
    workgroups[1] - value
    workgroups[2] - value
    workgroups[3] - value
    workgroups[4] - value
    workgroups[5] - value
    workgroups[6] - value

Is there a way to generate a variable name followed by a numeric value of the position counter or the xsl:number option?

I'm using MS Visual Studio to create the xsl in and the results will be  will be displayed using IE browsers.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($workgroups)/elem[0]"/>
```

Comment: that does not return a value either :(